# TPageControl tab area OnMouseEnter OnMouseLeave events

Tags: delphi, winapi

I need to catch the **"OnMouseEnter"** and **"0nMouseLeave"** for a certain area of the **TPageControl component**. With that specific area I mean **the whole "tab header" rectangle**.

The problem is, that the **page control doesn't catch the messages** (I'm catching internal control messages CM_MOUSEENTER and CM_MOUSELEAVE) **in the "empty" space**.

[image: screenshot]

The aim for me is to draw a small arrow in the right empty side when user hovers in the red framed area (and drawing is just piece of cake) and erase it when leaves this area. And I'm don't care about the overflow of the tabs (which causes to draw scrolling double button) - that will never happen.

Here is the working piece of code, **but it's not the clear solution and I don't like it**. There must be another (more clean) way to do it.

```
type
  TPageControl = class(ComCtrls.TPageControl)
  protected
    procedure CMMouseLeave(var Message: TMessage); message CM_MOUSELEAVE;
    procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;
  end;

procedure TPageControl.CMMouseLeave(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  Canvas.TextOut(Width - 130, 5, 'CMMouseLeave'); // display result
end;

procedure TPageControl.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
var TabHeaderRect: TRect;
begin
  if Message.Result = 0 then // if Message.Result = HTNOWHERE ...
    begin
      TabHeaderRect := ClientRect;
      TabHeaderRect.Bottom := Top + 21;

      if PtInRect(TabHeaderRect, ScreenToClient(Point(Message.XPos, Message.YPos))) then
        Canvas.TextOut(Width - 130, 5, 'WMNCHitTest   '); // display result

      Message.Result := HTCLIENT;
    end
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

Comment: I know it's surely possible to give e.g. panel with the proper height under the page control and share the same events for the page control's OnMouseEnter and OnMouseLeave and the panel, but I need to wrap this in one component seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the empty space does not belong to the control's client area and so the control doesn't get any mouse-related Windows messages for that area. You will have to use the form's mouse events. Or put the page control inside a panel (using `alClient`) and use the panel's mouse events.

If you need this more than once, you could create a new component that does exactly that (combine a panel and a page control to achieve the desired behaviour).

Comment: It would be possible somehow. Maybe using WM_NCHITTEST or something. As far as I tested, WindowFromPoint function returns TPageControl handle even for the empty area, so I hope there is some message catched by page control itself in this area. And the empty space belongs to the client area of the page control, isn't it ? I thought it's transparent because of erase background message.

Comment: @daemon - No, if it had been the client area, you would be getting your mouse enter/leave messages. Then try that, in the WM_NCHITTEST handler, if the hit test is HTTRANSPARENT modify it to be HTCLIENT, and see if the VCL's leave/enter events are firing.

Comment: +1 for you guys. This WM_NCHITTEST message makes me mad. The only problem is that I don't know when to capture and release the mouse. In the code above I haven't captured the mouse and it works. From my point of view I should watch (capture) the mouse when cursor enters the page control, but I don't know if user arrive with the cursor to the empty part. So I can never tell, yes you're under my empty space. That's the reason, why I accepted this answer. I'll modify TPageControl to create and place itself on the panel and assign OnMouseEnter and 0nMouseLeave to it. Thanx for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're handling OnMouseEnter/OnMouseLeave for the page control itself, and not for the TTabSheet instance that it contains?

Comment: Yop. I'm handling CM_MOUSEENTER and CM_MOUSELEAVE in my overriden TPageControl class.